# how to customize Id field of ApplicationUser

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I want to use Id field from application user (in sql server) in another tables (my scenario) but it contain guid value: (3dc2a0e7-d659-4d3b-81b3-2d067e256cd2) and I dont know it structure and it have not GUID type structure !

is there any way to change id structure in application or sql server or even declare a new type?

Comment: I don't fully follow your question/problem.  But, I might suggest that you always have an auto increment primary key in your tables.  In this case, you could use that primary key instead of the GUID (though it would still map to a specific GUID).

Comment: unfortunately this filed only contains guid and primary key . since default GUID and it filed is not sequential and it can cause a fragmentation issues on performance and i want to change type to DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() but i cant do it because table must rebuild and current structure confused

Comment: I agree with the part about "confused."

Answer (score 0):

you can change the default Id type from string(nvarchar) to int identity:
[Change Primary Key for Users in ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity#software-versions-used-in-the-tutorial)